# Green margins in Eclipse (luna)?

Tags: eclipse, xhtml, margins, eclipse-luna

I'm seeing these green margins on all of my .xhtml files - in addition, Eclipse seems to be running a little more slowly when the files are first opened.

[image]

In addition, Eclipse is updating classloader often and slowly while working in these files.
[image]

Any ideas as to what's going on?
How can I fix this?

I'm using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured this out - figured I'd post in case anyone ran into the same issue. It turns out that Eclipse was opening these files in the Web Page Editor. Once I switched back to the HTML Editor, all issues were resolved.